# How to type guillemets in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, hotkeys

How to type [guillemets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemets) ([book title mark in Chinese](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9B%B8%E5%90%8D%E8%99%9F)) in Emacs (efficiently)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most effective way of inputing Chinese punctuation characters such as `《` is probably using input method `chinese-punct`. Concretely, one can do it with the following steps:

- type `M-x C-l`
- type `chinese-punt`, then `Enter` to turn on chinese-punct input method
- type `<` and choose 3 for entering `《`
- enter `C-\` to toggle back to the default input method

Comment: What's M-x C-l? The way to choose an input method is C-x RET C-\.

Answer (score 2):

does this help? [Using ISO Latin 1 in Emacs](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/emacs-iso.html). I'm not sure what you mean by "book title marks in Chinese"

Enable iso-accents-mode then type:

~<   to get                  «

and

~>   to get              »

Comment: "book title marks in Chinese" is how guillements are used in Chinese and called. `iso-accents-mode` is an obsolete way of entering accented Latin letters and not likely an ideal solution for entering guillements. +1 for pointing the option out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an X environment, you can just simply use [Compose] [<] [<] or [Compose] [>] [>].

Comment: What is `[Compose]` and `[<]`, concretely?  I.e. what do I do on my keyboard?

Comment: That depends on your configuration. For [Compose], either [AltGr] or the Windows context menu key are usually used. In some desktop environments like KDE, you have to activate it in the system settings.